# How to use SPServices jquery to add new item

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery

I have a list and I would like to have a link on each item (dynamic) that I can click to insert some data to another list.

What I'm after is to get some data when a user clicks an item. (Kind of to track when they have read an item)

I have been trying to use SPServices but keep getting error.

```
i.replace is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

...pend(aa);H("#"+ab).find("option:contains('"+t+"'):eq(0)").attr("selected","selec...
```

This is what i'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Jquery/jquery.SPServices-0.6.2.min.js"></script>

    $(document).ready(function() { 
CreateNewItem(subject, message); 
}); 

function CreateNewItem(subject, message) { 
$().SPServices({ 
 operation: "UpdateListItems", 
 async: false, 
 batchCmd: "New", 
 listName: "TheOtherLIST", 
 valuepairs: [["Title", subject], ["Message", message]], 
 completefunc: function(xData, Status) { 
 alert("completed"); 
 } 
 });
}
```

Comment: I did get it working.
But i can't insert dates.What format does it need to be to insert dates?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: I believe using UTC time format is the preferred method, yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ.

Comment: Thanks PirateEric
This is what i'm trying to apss "2012-01-13T15:08:38Z" but its not working

Comment: Give this a shot to convert the dates:
$().SPServices.SPConvertDateToISO();

https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$%28%29.SPServices.SPConvertDateToISO